# Eclipse: Cannot use Hibernate tool plugin to generate cfg xml

Tags: eclipse, spring, hibernate, maven, slf4j

I followed the spring tutorial for building a restful executable jar.  http://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

I am using Eclipse, and I am configuring Hibernate for the first time.  I understand that the hibernate cfg xml files can be generated by an eclipse hibernate configuration plugin (as per http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-generate-code-with-hibernate-tools/).  I have installed that, and configured the connection to my database.

When I attempt to refresh the database view to see the child objects, I get the error:

```
An internal error occurred during: "Fetching children of Database".
org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
```

My POM is pretty simple.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mydomain</groupId>
    <artifactId>myapp</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>0.5.0.M6</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>         
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <start-class>com.mydomain.myapp.Application</start-class>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin> 
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId> 
                <!-- <version>2.3.2</version> --> 
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>          
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
            <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
            <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

I understand this problem can be caused by a dependency loading LocationAwareLogger that is conflicting with Hibernate when it runs to fetch the db children.

I have traced the parent poms back to spring-boot-dependencies https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-dependencies/pom.xml where I found slf4j loading.  I guess this is the problem.

I am getting out of my depth here.  How can I accomplish my aim of configuring the Hibernate eclipse plugin to generate my cfg.xml files?  Is there a way to exclude the slf4j that's loading in the grandparent pom?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you need to show all the dependency inheritance by `mvn depenenty:tree`, and then add maven dependency exclude to exclude the conflict dependency in other dependency, just using the hibernate one.

Comment: In eclipse, I can see the dependency heirarchy.  Slf4j is loading from spring-boot-starter-logging, called by spring-boot-starter, called by spring-boot-starter-web.  But those are in my parent pom, or my parent pom's parent.... How can I exclude those?

Comment: you can refer to http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Leo Huang was right when he pointed me to that document.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
    <scope>compile</scope>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions> 
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

I also happened to have the same problem and I had to exclude all the sl4j jars from the POM as mentioned above. **Important thing is to restart the Eclipse after that.**

Answer (score 0):

Remove all the slf4j configuration on the artifacts.xml of the eclipse. Then restart the eclipse and redo the hibernate tool process.

Answer (score 0):

A solution that avoids to modify the behaviour of your Project, so modifing only the Hibernare Tools plugin, is to edit the configuration of hibernate in your project:

1. Go to Classpath panel
2. Remove Project Entry classpath
3. Add External JARs libs of the hibernate tool plugin in the folder: eclipse\plugins\org.hibernate.eclipse.libs_3.7.1.Final-v20140303-0022-B124\lib\hibernate
4. comment temporarely in the pom.xml the block of library of logging SLF4J.
5. Restart Eclipse

After the use of the tools, restore pom.xml.